# Regex for special characters in java

Tags: java, regex, replace

```
public static final String specialChars1= "\\W\\S";
String str2 = str1.replaceAll(specialChars1, "").replace(" ", "+");

public static final String specialChars2 = "`~!@#$%^&*()_+[]\\;\',./{}|:\"<>?";
String str2 = str1.replaceAll(specialChars2, "").replace(" ", "+");
```

Whatever `str1` is I want all the characters other than letters and numbers to be removed, and spaces to be replaced by a plus sign (`+`).

My problem is if I use `specialChar1`, it does not remove some characters like `;`, `'`, `"`, and if I am use `specialChar2` it gives me an error :

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error U_REGEX_MISSING_CLOSE_BRACKET near index 32:
```

How can this be to achieved?. I have searched but could not find a perfect solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This worked for me:

`String result = str.replaceAll("[^\\dA-Za-z ]", "").replaceAll("\\s+", "+");`

For this input string:

> /*-+!@#$%^&*())";:[]{}\ |wetyk 678dfgh

It yielded this result:

> +wetyk+678dfgh

Comment: @Archie.bpgc: Sorry for the misunderstanding. The above should work though.

Comment: @npinti: remove the whitespace `..[^... ]`

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley: If I remove the white space from `[^\\dA-Za-z ]` it will catch the white space and replace it with an empty string. If I understood the OP correctly, he/she would like to remove the special characters and replace white spaces with a plus.

Comment: @Archie.bpgc: Glad it worked. Apologies for the initial misunderstanding.

Comment: I just wanted to show my friend how simple it is to do using replaceAll. he wanted me to use url encoding, once again thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

`replaceAll` expects a regex:

```
public static final String specialChars2 = "[`~!@#$%^&*()_+[\\]\\\\;\',./{}|:\"<>?]";
```

Comment: sry it gives me the same error :    java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error U_REGEX_MISSING_CLOSE_BRACKET near index 34:

Comment: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 33
[`~!@#$%^&*()_+[\]\\;',./{}|:"<>?]

Comment: escape the [ as well, like this
[`~!@#$%^&*()_+\\\[\\\]\\\\;\',./{}|:\"<>?]

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your first regex,  is that `"\W\S"` means find a sequence of two characters, the first of which is not a letter or a number followed by a character which is not whitespace.

What you mean is `"[^\w\s]"`. Which means: find a single character which is neither a letter nor a number nor whitespace. (we can't use `"[\W\S]"` as this means find a character which is not a letter or a number OR is not whitespace -- which is essentially all printable character).

The second regex is a problem because you are trying to use reserved characters without escaping them. You can enclose them in `[]` where **most** characters (not all) do not have special meanings, but the whole thing would look very messy and you have to check that you haven't missed out any punctuation.

Example:

```
String sequence = "qwe 123 :@~ ";

String withoutSpecialChars = sequence.replaceAll("[^\\w\\s]", "");

String spacesAsPluses = withoutSpecialChars.replaceAll("\\s", "+");

System.out.println("without special chars: '"+withoutSpecialChars+ '\'');
System.out.println("spaces as pluses: '"+spacesAsPluses+'\'');
```

This outputs:

```
without special chars: 'qwe 123  '
spaces as pluses: 'qwe+123++'
```

If you want to group multiple spaces into one `+` then use `"\s+"` as your regex instead (remember to escape the slash).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem to solve and I used following method:

```
text.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}+", "").replaceAll("\\s+", "+");
```

#### Code with time bench marking

```
public static String cleanPunctuations(String text) {
    return text.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}+", "").replaceAll("\\s+", "+");
}

public static void test(String in){
    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String out = cleanPunctuations(in);
    long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("In=" + in + "\nOut="+ out + "\nTime=" + (t2 - t1)+ "ms");

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "My text with 212354 digits spaces and \n newline \t tab " +
            "[`~!@#$%^&*()_+[\\\\]\\\\\\\\;\\',./{}|:\\\"<>?] special chars";
    test(s1);
    String s2 = "\"Sample Text=\"  with - minimal \t punctuation's";
    test(s2);
}
```

### Sample Output

```
In=My text with 212354 digits spaces and 
 newline     tab [`~!@#$%^&*()_+[\\]\\\\;\',./{}|:\"<>?] special chars
Out=My+text+with+212354+digits+spaces+and+newline+tab+special+chars
Time=4ms
In="Sample Text="  with - minimal    punctuation's
Out=Sample+Text+with+minimal+punctuations
Time=0ms
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a regex like this:

`[<#![CDATA[¢<(+|!$*);¬/¦,%_>?`:#="~{@}\]]]#>]`

**remove "#" at first and at end  from expression**

regards

Answer (score 0):

@npinti

using "\w" is the same as "\dA-Za-z"

This worked for me:

```
String result = str.replaceAll("[^\\w ]", "").replaceAll("\\s+", "+");
```