# Getting unexpected result with matcher.group(index)

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string and pattern:

```
String  = <html><body><input type="hidden" name="AvailabilityInputScheduleSelectView$market1" value="5~76AB~|VY~8001~"></input></body></html>
Pattern = AvailabilityInputScheduleSelectView$market1" value="(.*)|VY~(.*)~
```

I expected:

> m.group(0) = 5~76AB~ (characters matching the first (.*))
>
> m.group(1) = 8001 (characters matching the second (.*))

But I get:

> m.group(0) = VY~8001~
>
> m.group(1) = null
>
> m.group(2) = 8001

If I have only 2 patterns (.*), how can I get 3 groups (0,1,2)?

I've tried many combinations, but I'm not able to get the expected result.

I don't know if it's a problem with using not allowed characters inside pattern. I tried using quote method, but it doesn't work.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 4):

`group(0)` always returns the entire matched expression, and is the same as calling `group()` without arguments.
Your two groups will then be in group `1` and `2` respectively.

The reason one of your groups is `null` is because of the `|` , which has a special meaning in regexes, meaning `or`. Since only one side of the `or` will match each time, either `group(1)` or `group(2)` will return `null`, depending on which side didn't match. To get what you expected, change the `|` to `\\|`, to match a `|` character literally.

Comment: Thanks, but why m.group(2) is OK, but m.group(1) is getting null insted of 5~76AB~ ?

Answer (score 1):

Added escape to `$` and `|` and comsumed to end of String.

```
String str = "<html><body><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"AvailabilityInputScheduleSelectView$market1\" value=\"5~76AB~|VY~8001~\"></input></body></html>";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(".*AvailabilityInputScheduleSelectView\\$market1\" value=\"(.*)\\|VY~(.*)~.*").matcher(str);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println("Everything " + m.group(0));
    System.out.println("1st group: " + m.group(1));
    System.out.println("2nd group: " + m.group(2));
}
```

output:

```
Everything <html>..
1st group: 5~76AB~
2nd group: 8001
```

Although using regex to parse HTML is really a [bad idea](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

Comment: Thanks, now works !! I had also to escape the $ sign. Then comes me to another question. Is there any way to escape automatically theses characters to avoid errors like this?

Comment: Thanks Reimeus, Just the last question. Where can I find the list of characters that should be escaped in a pattern? I was taking a look at java 6 pattern class doc but it's not clear to me.

Comment: They appear in several places such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530942/regex-for-special-characters-in-java

Comment: @JBalaguero take a look at "Special Characters" from [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html).